# Proper OO design for State and Command

Tags: java, design, object-oriented

I'm working (a bit) on a (turn-based strategy) game. There are two classes relevant for the question:

- `State`: This is an immutable class, which exposes all its fields (either via getters or another way, as I felt appropriate). The state is a bit complicated, so I decomposed it into several classes in the package `...state`
- `Command`: This is an abstract immutable class with a couple of subclasses like `MoveCommand(Field from, Field to)`, `PassCommand()`, `BidCommand(int amount)`, etc. in the package `...command`. All of fields have public getters.

I need one of the two methods

- `State Command.applyTo(State)` or
- `State State.apply(Command)`

returning the new state (obtained by applying the command to the state).

Using the first method looks better at the first sight, since it dispatches to different implementations of `applyTo` in the subclasses of `Command`. Unfortunately, it forces me to fiddle with the many details of `State` in the class `Command`. In order to make it work, I need something like `MutableState`, or `State.Builder`, or a many-args constructor of `State`, or whatever.

Using the second method looks ugly, as it'd force me to use `instanceof` (or some other ugly way to simulate the virtual method dispatch). OTOH, it would concentrate the working with `State` in the class itself.

So I think the first method is the way to go. With `Command` and `State` each in its own package it means that `MutableState` (or whatever gets used for building the resulting `State`) need to be a public class since there are no `friend`s in Java. No real problem, but not nice, is it?

So what is the proper design?

Comment: Why is State immutable?  That's almost contradictory.  Immutable means stateless.  Stateful means mutable.  I don't get why you've created this problem for yourself.  Can you explain further how state can be immutable?

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't claim it's a good idea. The `State` never changes, it just gets replaced by another one (created from the `MutableState`). I'm considering dropping immutability but it wouldn't help much: The problem of `Command` fiddling with its data remains.

Comment: "The problem of Command fiddling with its data remains"?  The state has an API, does it not?  The `Command` uses that API to make change to the state, correct?  How is this a "problem"?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I'm leaning towards S.lott's thinking here.  To me, State should be mutable, although strictly bounded through an enum or similar tight  design.  YMMV of course

Comment: If you made `State` immutable for threading reasons, consider whether copying it would be preferable (then mutating it).  Alternatively, some immutable classes return copies of themself from setter methods - JodaTime returns a new `DateTime` instance every time the `addMinutes(1)` method is called - this allows the methods to be chained as appropriate.

Comment: @Martijn Verburg: "State should be mutable".  To me they are synonyms.  Stateful == Mutable.  I don't understand how it can be otherwise, and I'm hoping for an explanation of a stateless state object.

Comment: @S. Lott, in Python and similar languages, integers are immutable but that doesn't prevent them from representing state.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: Um.  That's not a very good example.  You usually represent state with a mutable variable and assign an integer value to that variable.  Representing state as "2" isn't sensible.  Representing state as `count= 2` is sensible.  The value of `count` changes.  That's what state usually means.  I'm hoping for an example of state that doesn't involve variables (or attributes of an object) that don't change.

Comment: @S. Lott, but that's exactly with the OP is doing. He's just got an object which is much more complex then a 2. He was a pointer to the current state. To change the state he replaces the object that pointer points to. Just like how you'd increment a count by replacing the integer object.

Comment: @Winston Ewert:  If, indeed, the "state" is just a really complex object, then a few static copies would be sufficient.  However, "forces me to fiddle with the many details of State in the class Command" says that it's not that simple.  It says that there's some details to the state and an immutable object isn't appropriate somehow.  Rather than conjecture, I'm looking for concrete details.

Comment: @S. Lott, I don't think the immutable object is appropriate. But I think he used one.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: You understood me correctly, and maybe immutability was indeed a bad idea here. Or maybe the only problem is that I've created an ugly API and it was just the ugliness which led to this question.

Comment: @maaartinus - Right, so I think the answer is to perhaps explore a mutable design.  It may seem like you're throwing away some existing work, but that's not necessarily a bad thing - you've just basically done some exploratory programming :-).

Answer (score 2):

Don't get too caught up on the State Pattern. This has a specific usage which I don't think necessarily applies in your game, at least not when you are manipulating the state of play.

Take, for example, a drawing application. In this case, the button pressed in the toolbar affects the way the drawing panel reacts to certain stimuli -- in this case, you don't want the application to know what it is going to do, you just want it to pass the stimulus to the State object and let it figure out what to do.

So, the rectangle drawing button is down, the application holds a RectangleDrawingState from which it can request a mouse-over pointer type or a mouse-down action or whatever. If you press the elipse-drawing button then that control switches out the RectangleDrawingState for an ElipseDrawingState and the application continues to ask for a mouse-over pointer type and a mouse-down action and gets completely different responses.

This is the kind of situation that makes for a good use-case for the State Pattern.

Now you *may* want this in your turn-based strategy game, to handle whether the attack button is pressed or the gather resources button is pressed. But you should handle the state of the game differently.

The state of the game should be handled as a single mutable object, which is manipulated at the end of each action. This object needs to be serializable in some form.

What you should do then is get a Command object by whatever means necessary and act on the mutable state-of-play object (it might be that your immutable State object, which depends on the action selected at any given time, returns a command which can act on the state-of-play object, for example).

Comment: I don't the see the OP is using the state pattern.

Comment: @Winston: Hard to be sure, now I read it back. That's how I took it, but you could be right.

Comment: @pdr: I am actually using neither the State nor the Command Patterns; in fact my State is `final` (but I'm going to use the Command Pattern for sending commands to the opponent). The classes just represent the state of the game and the user supplied command.

Comment: @maaartinus: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding, although the design I describe in the second half of the answer is still relevant, I believe. As for Undo, take a look at the Memento Pattern.

Comment: @pdr: My bad, I was quite confused as I was writing my question. Your answer was useful, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already know that Solution 2 is a bad plan. But solution 1 is giving you trouble as well.

I gather your classes end up looking like this:

```
class MoveCommand
{
   MoveCommand(Field from, Field to)
   {
      this->from = from;
      this->to = to;
   }

   State apply(State state)
   {
       MutableState mutable_state = new MutableState(state);
       Unit unit = mutable_state.GetUnit(from);
       mutable_state.RemoveUnit(from);
       mutable_state.PutUnit(to, unit);
       return mutable_state.AsState();
   }
}
```

Firstly, you've designed your immutable objects wrong. The idea is *not* to switch back and forth between immutable and mutable objects. Rather, if you want to use immutable objects, then methods on your immutable object should return new objects. So your code should look more like this.

```
State apply(State state)
{
    Unit unit = state.GetUnit(from);
    state = state.RemoveUnit(unit);
    state = state.PutUnit(to, unit);
    return state;
}
```

But immutability is great for small things like numbers, strings, etc. For handling the entire state of your game, it tends to get cumbersome. So really, I figure you should drop the immutable aspect and do:

```
void apply(State state)
{
    Unit unit = state.GetUnit(from);
    state.RemoveUnit(unit);
    state.PutUnit(to, unit);
}
```

However, an argument can be made that this makes the MoveCommand have logic that belong somewhere else. Perhaps the code should look like:

```
void apply(State state)
{
    state.move(from, to);
}
```

But this makes the whole MoveCommand class look a little pointless because it doesn't seem to really do anything. But I say: don't worry about it. Some commands will be trivially implemented using the game state objects. And that's a good thing.

Comment: Currently my classes indeed look like your first example, and I'm starting to like it. Using both the mutable and immutable state allows me to separate responsibilities better. I'll implement a bit more and see.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're fine using your first method.  You will probably want to utilize a StateBuilder to allow the command to build out the new state.

Thus you've divided your state, your commands (allowing you to roll back to prior states, I assume), and your means of building new states.

That said, I'm not sure what the immutable state is giving you in this case, beyond something with a handle that can be tracked or rolled back to.  If that is not your purpose, I don't know that you need it.

Comment: I think you're quite right. There are some advantages of the immutable State (thread-safety, clarity, and trivial rollback), but I'm not sure if it's worth it. Currently I've made some progress using both `State` and `MutableState`, and it looks fine. The overhead for having two such classes may be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should separate Command (a request) from its affects (a response). You have a set of concrete Command classes and the State objects will behave differently for each, so you should consider using overloaded methods for each Command. This allows you to specifically handle each Command as only the State should know how to respond. You Command objects have no inherent behaviour, only the data needed for the request.

`void State.Handle(MoveCommand)`

`void State.Handle(PassCommand)`

`void State.Handle(BidCommand)`

The `Handle` methods are responsible for validating the Command against current state, and then raising appropriate domain events to affect the state of the model. The domain events contains the new data to be applied interested parties (e.g. 'MovedEvent' contains new position).

The Apply methods accept concrete domain event objects and change the state accordingly:

`void State.Apply(MovedEvent)`

`void State.Apply(PassedEvent)`

`void State.Apply(BiddedEvent)`

Domain events could also be routed to other affected objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with some mixed design:

- The state consists of two parts:

  - `StateData` representing

    - the board
    - the card stacks of both players
    - and other long-term things
  - `StateControl` representing the intermediate steps like

    - when a player has selected an own unit as an attacker, but not yet the target
    - when one of many similar transient situation occurs

The latter uses the state pattern. Everything is immutable and I've dropped the mutable counterpart. With the help of Lombok [Wither](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither.html), it works just fine.

I'm using `Command.applyTo(State)` which sometimes just delegates to helper methods `State.apply(Command)`, so there are actually both variants.

The immutability lead to some unnecessary allocations like

```
State move(Field from, Field to) {
    Group g = getGroupFromField(from);
    return this
        .withField(from, EMPTY_GROUP) // throw-away state
        .withField(to, g);
}
```

but short-living objects are cheap and the object is actually rather small as it consists of a couple of references to other small immutable objects. Sometimes, there are more throw-away intermediates, which made me to use a mutable counterpart as a builder, but this was cluttering the design too much.

The immutability also made the code a bit longer, but surely less error-prone. It also saved me from coding any copying methods and I believe it'll show its advantages when/if I code the game AI.